# Are there any good resources/idioms for visually designing business applications?

Tags: winforms, ui-design

I think we're all aware of what "your company's line-of-business software" looks like.

[image: your company's application]
<sub>(source: [glompix.com](http://glompix.com/imagedump/simplicity-app.png))</sub>

Are there any resources, rules of advice, or general tricks to visually taming applications like this?  Our business's domain is pretty complex, as most are, and our customers demand a great amount of flexibility.  Tracking a boatload of fields on each object isn't exactly avoidable.

Besides general advice, I'm also interested in usage and tools specific to WinForms.  If there are any examples of (visually) well-designed software of this type, that would help as well.

Comment: [Design basics for Desktop applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/designprinciples) and [Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/guidelines) are very good Microsoft's resources about designing UI for Windows desktop applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a site that I visit every now and then to be reminded of what **not** to do:
[Interface Hall of Shame](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618005112/http://homepage.mac.com:80/bradster/iarchitect/shame.htm).

A [quick googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=ui%20mistakes&gws_rd=ssl) [turns this up](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-10-application-design-mistakes/), which goes more into detail of the most common UI mistakes, which boils down to:

1. Non-Standard GUI Controls

   1. Looking Like a GUI Control Without Being One
2. Inconsistency
3. No Perceived Affordance

   1. Tiny Click Targets
4. No Feedback

   1. Out to Lunch Without a Progress Indicator
5. Bad Error Messages
6. Asking for the Same Info Twice
7. No Default Values
8. Dumping Users into the App
9. Not Indicating How Info Will Be Used
10. System-Centric Features

---

There are some books that you should read too:

[image: The Design of Everyday Things]
<sub>(source: [mac.com](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/images/poet.gif))</sub>

[image: GUI Design for Dummies]
<sub>(source: [mac.com](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/images/arlov.gif))</sub>

[image: The Inmates are Running the Asylum: Why High Tech Products Drive Us Crazy and How To Restore the Sanity]
<sub>(source: [mac.com](http://homepage.mac.com/bradster/iarchitect/images/inmates.gif))</sub>

---

Mainly, try to use [the platform](https://web.archive.org/web/20110520072147/http://developer.kde.org:80/documentation/standards/kde/style/basics/index.html) [standard widgets](https://web.archive.org/web/20130114214127/https://developer.apple.com/ue/), [guidelines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop) [and](https://www.experiencedynamics.com/approach/ui-style-guides) [rules](http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:pwdugQnW2YUJ:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971323.aspx+windows+style+ui+design+standard&hl=es&gl=ar&strip=1).

Comment: There's some good organization type-stuff in the Interface Hall of Shame, and even some "here's what I would do instead" sort of things.  This is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a programmer who used to work in a publications department.  My advice is: Use a graphic designer; trust their opinions; and know if you are not one.

Here at the office, where we don't have a graphic designer, we have a bi-weekly "interface meeting" with a few developers and a few non-developers to hammer out these sorts of problems and develop design rules we can follow.

Comment: A graphic designer is not an usability expert.

Comment: That's a good point.  Though I would still argue that good graphic design is a key component in usability, if a lesser one.